# Problem with case and status

Tags: sql-server-2005

When I don't have right side I get NULL on column StatusOfDeduplication instead 5.

What is wrong with this query ?

```
select c.Code AS Code, c.DefaultName AS Name, c.Status AS Status,
 case cp.TargetCodeStatus when Null then 5  else cp.TargetCodeStatus end as StatusOfDeduplication from Cities c LEFT JOIN CityPackages cp ON cp.TargetCode = c.Code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL cannot be compared using equal or CASE WHEN. Use

```
ISNULL(cp.TargetCodeStatus, 5) AS StatusOfDeduplication
```

instead